# How to export only rejected comments for a pull request in github to Excel

Tags: git, github

**Scenario :**

I have forked a repository in github and i will be doing all the changes and will be updating my fork. I will be raising a pull request to the master with a code review request as well!. Suppose if owner rejects my changes may be due to some flaw in the code, and also owner will be adding some comments to it.

**My Question** :

How to export all such rejected comments to excel may be from last two months to current date?

**What i tried** :

I used the below command, but it didn't log rejected comments. It just logged only the comments given during the time of commit?

**git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"**

Comment: Reviews and comments are a feature of GitHub where as the `git` command deals with git  SCM and not GitHub. To work with GitHub features you will need to use GitHub API.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : You can't.

Long answer : You can't because that's part of Git(hub/lab/whatever-provider) services.

Like pull requests, Labels, Issues or CI statements, they are related to the website, not to Git